# ClassNotFoundException exception after adding external jar to spring WEBAPI

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am building a spring restful service for which I am adding third part jar with java build path 
1. I created lib folder in project and copied the jar to that file 
2. from there I have added that to build path.
3. When I run that project, I getClassNotFoundException.

anyone can suggest what should be the issue 
thanks

[image]

Comment: The issue is that a required class isn't on the classpath. How to solve it? Add it to the classpath. What are the exact steps? Impossible to tell without seeing your configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your jar file is not available at runtime.

In order for it to be available at runtime ,just add jar file in your java build path like this:

[image]

Hope this helps..!

Comment: I have added the jar to build path but still it give the error :(

Comment: @Shashikant, did you add jar to lib as well? Please share the screenshot of exception. So,that it will be easy to check.

Comment: I think you have problem with your classpath.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#Setting_the_path_to_execute_Java_programs  . Set the classpath based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to an old thread. I had a similar situation where I had to add a custom jar to my Spring Boot 2.7.1 maven based project like below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Custom</groupId>
        <artifactId>Custom</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/Custom.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

So now the jar is successfully under maven dependency but was still getting Class-not-found exception (e.g. abc.def.hij.SomeClass) which I was using in my @RestController as autowired. The fix was to use include my class package in base package scan in my Spring Application like below:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"abc.def.hij" , "klm.nop.qrs"})
```

And it worked just fine.